# error consulta php sql phpmyadmin en dato tipo SET , no regresa los datos correctamente (error de escritura)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

tengo una conculta a mi base de datos

```
function ticketsanulacionpendientesSISTEMAS($conexion){

        $pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 && status = 1 or status= 2 or status =3")) or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
        $resultados = mysqli_fetch_row($pendientes);
        return $resultados[0];
    }
```

donde el buscara de la tabla ticket, todos los creados cuyo tipo de solicitud sea el valor 1 y el status sea 1 , 2, 3...

la misma consulta la hago en el phpmyadmin

SELECT * FROM `ticket` WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 AND status =1 or status =2 or status =3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien sabe por que me pasa este error?

y cuando busco por 4  me sale el que me falta que en la base de dato tiene 3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ultima

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego de un 
SELECT * FROM ticket as T WHERE T.tipo_solicitud = 1 AND (T.status =1 or T.status =2 or T.status =3)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego de un IN

SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 AND status IN(1,2,3)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con comillas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi status

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solucion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76282/discussion-on-question-by-juan-ortiz-error-consulta-php-sql-phpmyadmin).

Comment: Sube la estructura de la tabla @JuanOrtiz

Comment: alli esta la solucion @WalterCordova, la ultima imagen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que la columna `status` es del tipo `SET`, por lo tanto, sus valores no son numéricos realmente, de modo que debes escribir los criterios entre comillas simples.

O sea, algo así:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ticket` 
WHERE `tipo_solicitud` = 1 AND (`status` = '1' OR `status` = '2' OR `status` = '3');
```

En cuanto a cambiarlo por un tipo de dato `INT`, eso dependerá siempre del alcance de tu aplicación. Decidir el tipo de dato a la hora de declarar una columna es tan simple como responder a la pregunta: ***¿qué almacenará mi columna?***. Si es una fecha, la declaras como fecha, si son números, como `INT`, si va a almacenar una colección, o sea, datos como `'1,2,3,4'`, como `SET`, etc, etc, etc. En tu caso, las columnas no parecen almacenar colecciones en sí, sino simples valores numéricos.

Esto es importante, sobre todo cuando la tabla crezca. Imagina una tabla con millones y millones de registros y declarada con tipos de datos no adecuados. Sería una tabla que crecería exponencialmente, aparte de las posibles consecuencias a pagar en cuanto a rapidez, mantenimiento, etc.

En cualquier caso, si decides cambiar el tipo de dato, primero, haz una copia de la tabla, y aplica una estrategia adecuada para hacer el cambio de tipo de dato.